# issue with clientHeight property on window events

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox

The below component should react to the changes in window resize based on the container height.

ISSUE: containerHeight variable correctly increases as I decrease the window size, however, when I make the window size bigger, the containerHeight does not decrease. It stays at its last maximum value.
*** The part that confuses me is that if I remove the "line-height: 1.25rem;" from the code-container class, the everything works perfectly!

Notes:

1. I am debouncing the resize handler to prevent the calculation from happening too often.
2. I am using flexbox for the code-container and line-numbers classes.

```js
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import styles from "./CodeBlock.module.css";

function debounce(fn, ms) {
  let timer;
  return (_) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout((_) => {
      timer = null;
      fn.apply(this, arguments);
    }, ms);
  };
}

const CodeBase = (props) => {
  const codeContainerRef = useRef(null);
  const [lineCount, setLineCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const debouncedHandleResize = debounce(() => {
      const lineHeight = 20; // Value based on CSS
      const containerHeight = codeContainerRef.current.clientHeight;
      console.log(containerHeight);
      const calculatedLineCount = Math.floor(containerHeight / lineHeight);
      setLineCount(calculatedLineCount);
    }, 500);
    debouncedHandleResize();
    window.addEventListener("resize", debouncedHandleResize);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", debouncedHandleResize);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={styles["code-container"]} ref={codeContainerRef}>
      <div className={styles["line-numbers"]}>
        {Array.from({ length: lineCount }, (_, index) => (
          <div key={index + 1} className={styles["line-number"]}>
            {index + 1}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className={styles["code-line"]}>{props.children}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CodeBase;
```

And here is the CSS code:

```css
    .code-container {
      display: flex;
      line-height: 1.25rem;
    }
    
    .line-numbers {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      max-height: 100%; /*Ensure it doesn't exceed container height */
    }
    
    .line-number {
      color: #777;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    
    .code {
      overflow-x: auto;
      white-space: pre-wrap;
    }
    
    .code-line {
      padding-left: 8px; /* Add spacing between line numbers and code */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This typically happens when you're using an import statement in an environment that doesn't support ES Modules, like a browser environment without module support.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import styles from "./CodeBlock.module.css";

function debounce(fn, ms) {
  let timer;
  return (_) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout((_) => {
      timer = null;
      fn.apply(this, arguments);
    }, ms);
  };
}

const CodeBlock = (props) => {
  const codeContainerRef = useRef(null);
  const [lineCount, setLineCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const debouncedHandleResize = debounce(() => {
      const lineHeight = 20; // Value based on CSS
      const containerHeight = codeContainerRef.current.clientHeight;
      const calculatedLineCount = Math.floor(containerHeight / lineHeight);
      setLineCount(calculatedLineCount);
    }, 500);
    
    debouncedHandleResize();
    window.addEventListener("resize", debouncedHandleResize);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", debouncedHandleResize);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={styles["code-container"]} ref={codeContainerRef}>
      <div className={styles["line-numbers"]}>
        {Array.from({ length: lineCount }, (_, index) => (
          <div key={index + 1} className={styles["line-number"]}>
            {index + 1}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className={styles["code-line"]}>{props.children}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CodeBlock;
```

And in CSS code you need to update your class names...

```
/* CodeBlock.module.css */
.code-container {
  display: flex;
  line-height: 1.25rem;
}

.line-numbers {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 100%; /* Ensure it doesn't exceed container height */
}

.line-number {
  color: #777;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.code-line {
  padding-left: 8px; /* Add spacing between line numbers and code */
}
```